# Libgdx: Cursor position after catching

Tags: java, libgdx, cursor, coordinates, cursor-position

I tried to hide the cursor image by setting the catch-flag to true:

```
   Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(true);
```

That works fine. After a while the flag is set back to false.

```
   Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(false);
```

The problem is that the cursor position where it reappears is upside down. When the cursor is moved to the top while it is invisible, the cursor reappears at the bottom. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you setting the cursor position manually? Setting the mouse location uses the y down orientation compared to libgdx y up orientation. A way to fix this is to set the mouse location using Gdx.input.setCursorPosition(mousex,screenheight - mousey);

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I don't set cursor position manually and for some reason your suggestion didn't worked. Anyway, I implemented a work around for the setCatched(...) method by replacing the cursor sprite with fully transparent image. So it's solved :)